# can I use ocean modifier on any custom shape?

Tags: modifiers

i am working on a ship in a bottle and want to animate the water inside the bottle with the ship floating on it. Is this possible with Blender 2.7a?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.
Set the ocean modifier to *displace* instead of generate:

[image]

Note that your mesh must be pretty highly subdivided for it to work well.